# Marshal a structure as a different structure in c#

Tags: c#, .net, memory, structure, marshalling

Lets start with defining my structures:

```
public struct structure1
{
    Int16 num1;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 200)]
    byte[] unmanaged;
}
public struct structure2
{
    Int16 num1;
    Int16 num2;
}
public struct structure3
{
    Int16 num1;
    Int32 num2;
    Int16 num3;
}
```

I wan't to "marshal" a managed structure as a diffrent structure, lets say from structure1 to structure3.

Visualization:

```
/----------------------------------structure1----------------------------------------------...
/-------num1--------|-----------------------------------unmanaged--------------------------...
|--Byte1--|--Byte2--|--Byte3--|--Byte4--|--Byte5--|--Byte6--|--Byte7--|--Byte8--|--Byte9--|...
\-------num1--------|-----------------num2------------------|--------num3-------/
\----------------------------------structure3-----------------------------------/
```

(I know that basically what I am doing in structure1 is a union of structure2 and structure3 and I could use the *FieldOffset* attribute to write all 3 structures in a single structure, but in my real case it is impossible to know the actual offset and it could change)

I wrote a solution but I think it is a bad, because each time I want to "cast" the structures, I need to allocated more unmanaged memory (and then remember to free it) and I don't realy need it, basically is there a better way to do:

```
    private TO ReMarshal<FROM, TO>(FROM structure)
    {
        IntPtr unmanaged_address = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf<FROM>());
        Marshal.StructureToPtr<FROM>(structure, unmanaged_address, false);
        return Marshal.PtrToStructure<TO>(unmanaged_address);
    }
```

Comment: You could create an overlay using FieldOffset(0) :     [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct structure
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public Structure2 structure2;
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public Structure3 structure3;
    }

Comment: @jdweng Ok, but lets say you get a result from a function and it is structure1 how can you convert it to the overlay structure? (or to any other stucture) without changing the function.

Comment: There is no conversion.  You put the return structure from c++ into my structure.  Then you can read in c# as either structure 1 or structure 2.

Comment: @jdweng wow your right, I didn't think about that. thank you. if you'd write and answer I would aprove it :)

Comment: Looks like code that tries to avoid BinaryReader too much.